# Why Prettier adds a random space before angle bracket in styled-components?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, prettier, css-variables

This is my code before prettier:

[image]

After saving Prettier adds a random space before the `$` sign, like this:

[image]

This space ruins my code, I know I can use `// prettier-disable` to skip the line, but my CSS code is big. Any solutions?

Comment: https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/7207#issuecomment-580227281

Comment: @devserkan Thanks for the reference, I may sound dumb... but what should I do ? do I have to wait for them to push the changes?

Comment: No, you don't sound dumb because probably there isn't any solution other than waiting for them to fix this in the announced version. Maybe there is a workaround but I couldn't find one. You can ask on Github about the date they plan to release it.